# Packing libraries into Blend - again, but different!

Tags: packed-data, packing

so, I'm desperately trying to upload this Blend to Renderstreet.
In order of appearance:

1. IES won't pack. OK, figured how to integrate the code in scripting area. Not "user friendly", though.
2. External libraries are missing. I'm supposed to make all paths relative.
3. Packing everything into Blend doesn't work. External libraries are missing.
4. Making paths relative doesn't work. 192 out of 401 failed.
5. The F3-accessible "Pack Blender libraries" command: "Cannot pack absolute file" - loop of poop

I'm suspecting this happens, because these are sitting in cloud files, or are on a different disk than the blend (thus, I can't make relative paths in Win 10, according to my findings). Either way, this would be stupid.

Is there a workaround that's not from 2015?

Blender 2.93.4 LTS, Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Markus,

The easiest way to do it is to use RenderStreet's add-on to upload the project. It will do all the collecting for you and upload the file.

The second-best solution would be to ask RenderStreet's support, as you can definitely get help there.

Comment: Hi Marius,

I wasn't complaining about renderstreet at all, it just showed me there's something deeply wrong with either, more likely my or Blender's system of handling external data. Because I also can't get this project to render on my 2nd computer for the very same reason.

Comment: Btw - the addon worked flawlessly and 40 mins/$2.50 for a render instead 30 hours + 30 KWh of electricity is a very good deal. I'm now your customer.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, Markus. Good to have you onboard, and we'll have your back from now on!